# Круглые скобки сразу после условия if

Tags: c++, if

Встретил такой код (выводит целое число в двоичном виде):

```
void f(const int n) 
{ 
    if (n) (f(n >> 1), std::cout << (n & 1)); 
}
```

И я абсолютно не понимаю как это работает. Нигде не смог найти информацию. Может кто-нибудь пояснить?

Comment: ваш пример не раскрывает всю мощь оператора запятая. результат последнего выражения передаётся для обработки в другие функции. то-же самое можно написать так : `if (n) std::cout << (f(n >> 1) , (n & 1));`

Answer (score 3):

После if(условие) может быть оператор (statement). Если их несколько, то нужно взять в фигурные скобки.

Посмотрим на такой код

```
if (n > 0) f(n);
```

в этом случае отсутствие скобок не должно смущать.

Взятие в круглые скобки - это просто выражение (в данном случае там два выражения, но это такое дело).

То есть, это все можно переписать вот так

```
void f(const int n) 
{ 
    if (n != 0) { f(n >> 1); std::cout << (n & 1)}; 
}
```

А исходный код лучше в приличном обществе не писать.

Comment: То есть через запятую просто последовательный вызов, понятно...Глупый вопрос :) Спасибо большое.

Comment: это "оператор запятая" с очень низким приоритетом.

Answer (score 2):

Эти скобки ничего не делают - без них код продолжит работать как и раньше.

Возможно, они нужны, чтобы линтер не выдавал предупреждение на оператор запятая (для eslint есть такое правило, что у си - не знаю).

Оператор запятая последовательно вычисляет левую и правую части, после чего возвращает значение правой. Конкретно в данном коде причин пихать несколько действий в один statement я не вижу, но в некоторых случаях может оказаться, что [разница есть](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/731506/178988).